# How to obtain Pair Distance column in summary (MatchIt)

Tags: r, matching, summary

I'm trying to compare different CEM matchings, unfortunately the MatchIt package does not have the L statistic therefore I wanted to compare the Pair Distance conlumn that can be obained with the summary function

How can I print only that column? (Since I apply several trials in the original dataset and the variables are a lot I would like to avoid copy and paste)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(MatchIt)

data(lalonde)

cem1 <- matchit(treat ~ age + re74 + re75, data = lalonde, 
                 method = "cem")

cem2 <- matchit(treat ~ age + re74 + re75, data = lalonde, 
               method = "cem",
               cutpoints= list(age = c(20.5, 25.5, 30.5,35.5,40.5))
               )

summary(cem1, un=TRUE)
summary(cem2, un=TRUE)
```

resutls I get

```
Call:
matchit(formula = treat ~ age + re74 + re75, data = lalonde, 
    method = "cem", cutpoints = list(age = c(20.5, 25.5, 30.5, 
        35.5, 40.5)))

Summary of Balance for All Data:
     Means Treated Means Control Std. Mean Diff. Var. Ratio eCDF Mean eCDF Max
age        25.8162       28.0303         -0.3094     0.4400    0.0813   0.1577
re74     2095.5737     5619.2365         -0.7211     0.5181    0.2248   0.4470
re75     1532.0553     2466.4844         -0.2903     0.9563    0.1342   0.2876


Summary of Balance for Matched Data:
    Means Treated Means Control Std. Mean Diff. Var. Ratio eCDF Mean eCDF Max Std. Pair 
                                                                                   Dist.
age        25.6286       25.8312         -0.0283     0.6863    0.0222   0.0619     0.2364     
re74     1299.0813     1755.5500         -0.0934     1.1026    0.0672   0.3764     0.1321     
re75     1016.9323     1228.5970         -0.0657     1.0062    0.0471   0.1852     0.1617    

Percent Balance Improvement:
     Std. Mean Diff. Var. Ratio eCDF Mean eCDF Max
age             90.8       54.1      72.7     60.8
re74            87.0       85.1      70.1     15.8
re75            77.3       86.2      64.9     35.6

Sample Sizes:
              Control Treated
All            429.       185
Matched (ESS)  169.79     175
Matched        288.       175
Unmatched      141.        10
Discarded        0.         0
```

what I would like to get a table like this one more or less

```
       cem1          cem2
       Pair. Dist.   Pair. Dist. 
age    0.1616        0.2364
re74   0.1289        0.1321 
re75   0.1671        0.1617
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `summary()` output is just a list. You can look at its details using `str()`.

To get just the columns of interest, use the following:

```
cbind(
  summary(cem1)$sum.matched[,"Std. Pair Dist."],
  summary(cem2)$sum.matched[,"Std. Pair Dist."]
)
```